# R - concerns when merging with different datetime classes, formats, and other arguments

Tags: r, dplyr, time-series, tidyverse

I have been guessing if this question should go here or in `MetaExchange` or in `Cross Validated` because could be interpreted as too broad/non-specific here. So I will try to be as specific as possible.

Let's assume I have two datasets. Both of them have one date column each, but one of them is character class and the other was automatically transformed to `put-your-less-favorite-date-class-here` when you did read the dataset.

The easiest way to do it is simply transforming both columns to the same format (i.e. `YYYY/mm/dd`), then transforming to character, and then merging. Easy. However, if you need to play with those date columns again you will have to transform them back to `put-your-favorite-date-class-here`, which turns you (I think) into an inefficient code-writer.

And I'm trying to be a more efficient one, so I'm merging both datasets with both of their classes as date. However, some questions arise:

- If both columns are dates with the same format and the same class but with different timezones, will be a problem? (I don't think so but I'm not 100% sure if a counterexample exist, hence the question)
- If both columns are dates with the same format and different class (i.e. one is stored internally as year, months, days, and the other column is stored as seconds from 1900), the merge is done with both dates stored internally? If it does, is R smart enough to compare them and quickly conclude which ones are the same even if they are stored differently internally?
- It's the same logic for datetimes? If it's the same datetime class, format, but different timezones, is R smart enough to recognize two equal datetimes with different timezones and with different/same class and format?

At the end, the question is: How a (1) date or (2) datetime merge strictly work in terms of different or same (1) class, (2) format, and (3) timezones when you are merging?

Currently I'm using tidyverse/dplyr for default, and strptime(), strftime() to do my transformations in this example. Tried datatable a few times but didn't like its syntax. If you think you have a better alternative to those ones, feel free to propose them! (this means the tags I put are not specifically aimed to expect a solution only from those packages, they are just the ones I use)

Comment: IMHO, Stackoverflow (SO) is for programming questions. A programming question should have an example data along with expected output.I don't think SO is good place for explanation of theoretical concepts or validation of it. (Although there are examples of such questions on the site).

Comment: @RonakShah I am with you. Nonetheless ... Chris, you are making the right observations. You should handle dates as date throughout your analysis workflow to avoid transforming and retransforming. In the end, this is what type-classes are for! As you use the tidyverse, look at the `{lubridate}` package. You will get the handling of timezone problems "built in".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in comments, using `lubridate` allows to simplify these questions.

Without `lubridate`:

```r
date1 <- as.Date('2021-01-01')
datetime1 <- as.POSIXct('2021-01-01 00:00:00',tz='UTC')
datetime2 <- as.POSIXlt('2021-01-01 00:00:00',tz='UTC')

date1 == datetime1
#> Warning: Incompatible methods ("Ops.Date", "Ops.POSIXt") for "=="
#> [1] FALSE
date1 == datetime2
#> Warning: Incompatible methods ("Ops.Date", "Ops.POSIXt") for "=="
#>   sec   min  hour  mday   mon  year  wday  yday isdst 
#> FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

With `lubridate`:

```
library(lubridate)

date1 == datetime1
[1] TRUE
date1 == datetime2
[1] TRUE
```

One important point is that `lubridate` attributes `UTC` timezone to `Date`:

```
lubridate::tz(Sys.Date())
[1] "UTC"
```